# PHP Mysql installation

Tags: mysql

I messed up my Mysql and php installation. I get the following error when I try to uninstall php, can some one help? Thank you :)

```
$ sudo apt-get purge php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

  phpmyadmin: Depends: php5-mysql but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5-mysqli but it is not installable

              Depends: php5-mcrypt but it is not going to be installed

              Depends: dbconfig-common but it is not going to be installed

              Depends: libjs-mootools (>= 1.2.4.0~debian1-1) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: php5-gd but it is not going to be installed

              Recommends: mysql-client

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
aptitude search php5

to see what php packages you got installed.

then do:

sudo aptitude purge php5-package1 php5-package2